# Why does Perl file test operator "-l" not detect symlinks?

Tags: perl, file, symlink

Why does the Perl file test operator "-l" fail to detect symlinks under the following conditions?

**System Info**

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ uname -a
Linux Apophis-LT 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 14:13:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:        17.10
Codename:       artful
```

**Perl Info**

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 0 (v5.26.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi (with 56 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

**Test Resources**

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ touch regular_file
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ mkdir dir
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ ln -s regular_file symlink

john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 john john 4096 May  6 02:29 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 john john 4096 May  6 02:29 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 john john 4096 May  6 02:29 dir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john    0 May  6 02:29 regular_file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 john john   12 May  6 02:29 symlink -> regular_file
```

**Script Containing Failing "-l" Operator**

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ cat ~/.scripts/test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd 'abs_path';

my $targetDir = "/temp2/test";
opendir(DIR, $targetDir) || die "Can't open $targetDir: $!";

while (readdir DIR) {
    my $file = "$_";

    if($file =~ m/^\.{1,2}/) {
        next;
    }

    $file = abs_path($file);

    if(-l "$file") {
        print "Link: $file\n";
    }
    elsif(-d "$file") {
        print "Dir: $file\n";
    }
    elsif(-f "$file") {
        print "File: $file\n";
    }
    else {
        print "\n\n *** Unhandled file type for file [$file]!\n\n";
        exit 1;
    }
}

closedir(DIR);
```

**Script Output**

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ perl ~/.scripts/test.pl
File: /temp2/test/regular_file
Dir: /temp2/test/dir
File: /temp2/test/regular_file
```

**Problem I'm Trying to Solve**

Note in the above output that the symlink (named "symlink") is not listed while the file, "regular_file," is listed twice (I want "symlink" listed -- the actual link and **not** the file it points to).

When I change `... if(-l "$file") ...` to `... if(lstat "$file") ...` in the script, again "symlink" is not listed while "regular_file" is listed twice, but they are being listed from within the block meant to catch symlinks, *i.e.*:

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ perl ~/.scripts/test.pl
Link: /temp2/test/regular_file
Link: /temp2/test/dir
Link: /temp2/test/regular_file
```

**Goal**

The output I'm trying to achieve (***which is faked below -- not actually generated by the script, but by hand***) is:

```
john@testbed-LT:/temp2/test$ perl ~/.scripts/test.pl
File: /temp2/test/regular_file
Dir: /temp2/test/dir
Link: /temp2/test/symlink
```

...but not necessarily in that order (I don't care about the order of the listing).

Why is the above-shown script not achieving the above-stated goal (why is the "-l" operator not working)?

Comment: Perl is not an acronym.

Comment: `$file = abs_path($file);` should be `$file = "$targetDir/$file";`. I don't have time to look for more problems right now.

Comment: Why do you keep using `"$file"` instead of `$file`?

Comment: @ikegami: Because, once I have this simple test working, I plan to expand it to recurse directories, where some paths may contain spaces, and, since I'm relatively new to Perl, I thought it safer to quote $file in case it contains spaces (or other characters) that might cause confusion.

Comment: @JohnDoe There's nothing "unsafe' about spaces. `$file` is just a variable; it can contain any string it wants. Perl is not the shell; it does not evaluate commands by repeated text substitution.

Comment: @John Doe, What are you talking about? The only difference bewteen `-l "$file"` and `-l $file` is the the first makes a needless copy of the value of `$file`.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for clarifying this.  I've been a programmer for a long time in other languages, but I haven't used Perl since its early versions, years ago, so I am by no means an expert when it comes to Perl.  So, I was stuck in a mode of thinking in terms of how BASH expands values and forgetting how Perl handles scalar assignments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`perldoc Cwd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd#abs_path1):

> **abs_path**
>
> ```
> my $abs_path = abs_path($file);
> ```
>
> Uses the same algorithm as getcwd(). **Symbolic links** and relative-path components ("." and "..") **are resolved** to return the canonical pathname, just like realpath(3). On error returns `undef`, with `$!` set to indicate the error.

(Emphasis mine.)

If you want to see symlinks, don't use `abs_path`.

What you want to do instead is

```
$file = "$targetDir/$file";
```

i.e. prepend the name of the directory you read `$file` from.

---

Additional notes:

```
opendir(DIR, $targetDir) || die "Can't open $targetDir: $!";

while (readdir DIR) {
    my $file = "$_";
```

should be

```
opendir(my $dh, $targetDir) || die "Can't open $targetDir: $!";

while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
```

- Why use bareword filehandles when you can just use normal variables (that are scoped properly)?
- There's no reason to quote `"$_"` here.
- Why first assign to `$_` when you're just going to copy the string to `$file` in the next step?

Comment: Great explanation.  I was previously using a variable as a filehandle.  I changed to bareword filehandle grasping at straws.  Regarding the quotes, I was stuck thinking in terms of BASH expansion and anticipating having paths containing spaces and non-alphanumeric characters (needed a mind shift).  I assign $_ to $file (1) for readability, as the script will be greatly expanded and the current file will be accessed a lot in the final script, and (2) because I will eventually also be performing operations on both raw-listed symlinks and the files pointed to (separately stored).

Comment: @JohnDoe Assigning `$_` to `$file` does not increase readability if you can just cut out `$_` and read into `$file` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

> *Note in the above output that the symlink (named "symlink") is not listed while the file, "regular_file," is listed twice*

Yeah, because you used `abs_path` to turn `symlink` into `/temp2/test/regular_file`. Get rid of that line.

---

By the way, you are missing

```
$file = "$targetDir/$file";
```

The only reason your program worked without it is because `$targetDir` happened to be the current work directory.

Comment: "The only reason your program worked without it is because $targetDir happened to be the current work directory."  Yes, I did notice this after I posted my question last night.  Thanks!